# Can we use the same Device ID for all the concurrent users during mobile load testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am performing mobile load testing.
And in one of the request there is device ID also captured, so not able to figure out how to proceed

Checked with single decide ID only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it's handled on the system under test side, if it's not used for identifying the user for i.e. advertising or tracking purposes you can leave the hard-coded value.

If it's used somehow and multiple occurrences will cause the system to group different requests as they're made by a single user - my expectation is that you need either to come up with a set of device IDs, put them into CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each thread (virtual user) could have its own device ID.

Alternatively you can generate an unique ID every time you run your test, for example iOS device IDs seemd to be normal [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) so you can use [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function to generate one.

Android device IDs are random alphanumeric strings so you could use [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function to generate one on the fly.

More information on [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) concept: